# How to find this limit : $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{2-\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2 +\sqrt{2+ \cdots n \text{ times}}}}}{4^{-n}}$

Tags: calculus, limits

How to find this limit :

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{2-\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2 +\sqrt{2+ \cdots n \text{ times}}}}}{4^{-n}}$$

Please help not getting any idea how to solve this , will be of great help thanks.

Comment: Are you sure that the first sign is a minus and the rest are pluses? Also are you sure that it is $4^{-n}$ in the denominator? And when you say "$n$ times", do you mean that there are $n$ $2$s in the numerator? Or $n$ square roots?

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**: Let $a_n = \sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\cdots \text{n times}}}}\Rightarrow a_n = \sqrt{2+a_{n-1}}$, and by induction on $n \geq 2$ you can prove that $a_n > a_{n-1}$,and  $0 <a_n < 2$. Thus you can let $a_n = 2\cos \theta_n$ with $\theta_n \in \left(0, \dfrac{\pi}{2}\right)\Rightarrow a_n = \sqrt{2+a_{n-1}}=\sqrt{2+2\cos \theta_{n-1}}= 2\cos \left(\dfrac{\theta_{n-1}}{2}\right) \Rightarrow \theta_n = \dfrac{\theta_{n-1}}{2}\Rightarrow a_n = 2\cos\left(\dfrac{\theta_1}{2^{n-1}}\right)$, and $\sqrt{2} = a_1 = 2\cos \theta_1 \Rightarrow \theta_1 = \dfrac{\pi}{4}\Rightarrow a_n = 2\cos \left(\dfrac{\pi}{2^{n+1}}\right)$. Thus you need only to calculate the limit $L = \displaystyle \lim_{n\to \infty} 4^n\left(2-2\cos\left(\dfrac{\pi}{2^{n+1}}\right)\right)$. Can you continue from this point?